# Getting Constant Height Of Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I'm trying to make auto-scroll for my `div`. Whenever I'm check height of that `div`, it gives me "200px" as it is in CSS. I think that it somehow because of CSS styles. [How to fix it](http://jsfiddle.net/G7aN2/)?

Idea of this all is that users may submit messages to chat, then they will appear in that box. I need to auto-scroll that box to the bottom...

Comment: You see, in should be more than 200px when users are submitted more than 200 messages. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div').prop('scrollHeight');
```

before jQuery 1.6, `prop` should be `attr`.

or just hit the HTML property:

```
$('div')[0].scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use JQuery and either use the ScrollTo plugin to scroll your content with animation, or use ScrollTop and just set the scroll to the scrollheight, like so;

$("div").ScrollTop($("div").ScrollTop());

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't even need to find out the height of the div. Based on your goals, you could just scroll it to max. Try something like this, inside the same function that adds new elements to your div:

```
<script>
$('#screameria form').submit(function() {
    var screams = $('#screameria .screams');
    screams.append(
        '<div>'
        + new Date()
        + ': '
        + $(this.scream).val()
        + '</div>'
    );
    screams.scrollTop(999999999);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

[Here's a jsFiddle with it](http://jsfiddle.net/JHbcu/)

Comment: I like the answer from Patrick Gates. Look around for plugins that already accomplish your goal, instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: Look at my code... I used height() already, but it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice the jsFiddle at first. I now see that you're already using `.height()`